# Facebook API não encontra usuário logado

Tags: php, facebook

Eu minimizei o meu código o mínimo possível, a fim de isolar o erro. Já revirei o fórum a procura de uma resposta simples, mas nenhuma dica resolveu este problema básico.

Nas configurações do app, as únicas alterações que fiz foram preencher a url (localhost:81/mb - já fiz publicando o arquivo e alterando o domínio e o resultado foi o mesmo) e defini no App Center Permissions a cláusula Default Activity Privacy como Pública. Preciso fazer algo mais?

Esta é uma página em PHP:

```
include_once 'libs/facebook/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '###',
    'secret' => '###',
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

if($user == null) {
    print_r("user null " . $user);
} else {
    print_r("user logged" . $user);
}
```

Apesar de estar logado no facebook e utilizar outra aba do Chrome o resultado é "user null 0".

Comment: Você deu permissão pra sua aplicação com a conta do usuário?

Comment: Em que momento essas permissões precisam ser dadas? Eu configurei o dominío do site na sessão desenvolvedor do facebook.

Comment: Quando tu tenta entrar no site, é pra ele desviar automaticamente pro facebook, pro perfil permitir acesso as informações da app.
Além disso, qual URL você colocou pra app? Se você tiver testando localmente, precisa colocar localhost mesmo.
Além disso, onde tem `###` estão o ID e o secret da app né? Senão, nem chance de funfar.

Comment: Felipe, sim para tudo o que você citou: estou testando localmente e a URL salva é localhost e os códigos appID e Secret estão devidamente copiados da mesma página do app no Facebook. E ainda assim, user = null.

Comment: Provavelmente o usuário não está logado no Facebook quando acessa a sua página. No SDK para Javascript (com o qual eu tenho alguma experiência), dá pra requisitar o login, mas no SDK para PHP eu honestamente não sei. Olhando esse exemplo oficial, parece que você precisa oferecer um link para o login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/

Comment: É exatamente isso, você não deve tá requisitando o login. Quando o $user for igual a `null`, você deve usar: 
`$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';`

Comment: Luiz, Felipe - apesar do usuário já estar logado, afinal eu estava utilizando o facebook na aba vizinha (talvez eu não esteja compreendendo o conceito de logado), criei o HREF para que ele se logasse. Quando clico no "login", a URL se altera "?code=XXXXX", mas nada acontece. F5 não muda nada...

Comment: Então, cara, o que acontece quando tu clica no login é te redirecionar para o facebook e, de lá, tu dar as permissões pra app. Tipo quando tu vai acessar um jogo novo, que diz que o aplicativo pode publicar coisas no seu mural no seu lugar, etc...

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu queria que acontecesse... Mas apenas aparece esta URL: http://localhost:81/mb/post_stalker.php?code=AQCpB3NXpLwoMhByluCi2hQ-gzuSO9OqJ3R_Y2WU1IVSPWLuvPbRT9G3MOy3V6sPBGBmnx8zTryXM1-FIGCW2lsv276VaIWFiM2wHszxFCESjjhywQNzAG4RMijprurOpyxgO5ap3RHfX6nTRLDzp57J08zRcq_6HUWz9mIO5oM8TUy2hSUtbcifqSO2RkazDWk2j7Lxqb_0HX3Ffi91ZacgHnCjqrsTCJTJGEydIdM7wpvZ9XD-wAO6ZXeHnQJRqJ7cSoufAdHaXxzkpoQ1JEpyFXc2rhmbrHqsk-roB78gMNYYUeTiC3pjiYD887-JmLY&state=b1385f1e529f520c3ca8733e00ed2141#_=_

Comment: Ah, entendi, não tá aparecendo a página de permissões, é isso? PARECE SER problema com as configurações da app.

Comment: Nas configurações do app, as únicas alterações que fiz foram preencher a url (http://localhost:81/mb) e defini no **App Center Permissions** a cláusula Default Activity Privacy como Pública. Preciso fazer algo mais?

Comment: O ideal é colocar o máximo de informações possíveis editando a própria pergunta para facilitar para todos entenderem o problema. Se as novas informações ficarem só nos comentários, as chances de obter uma resposta diminuem.

Comment: Tem que ser a porta 81 mesmo? Talvez seja por isso...

Comment: Pensei nisso também. Já fiz o upload para o domínio e continuou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Adicione na array de inicialização do objeto 'status' => true

Comment: Coloca o que você editou em uma resposta explicando como fez para resolver o problema.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Já tinha editado na própria pergunta e agora criei uma resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava na configuração do app no Facebook. Para resolvê-lo tive que ajustar essa opção:

> Do you want do make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

na aba Status & Reviews.

Comment: Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta. Aí do lado esquerdo, abaixo dos votos.